# RemoteRestRuntimeFactory cannot be resolved for jBPM6

Tags: java, jbpm

I want to access web service written in jBPM6 using restapi, i search through internet and found one example , here in example they have used RemoteRestRuntimeFactory class but i am not able to find any related jar file to resolve error for  cannot be resolved to a type. can anyone please help me to find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's in kie-services-client jar:
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/kie/remote/kie-services-client/6.0.1.Final/kie-services-client-6.0.1.Final.jar

Comment: thanks for quick response. I have updated the my code but now i am getting error for org.kie.internal.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession even though i have included jar files for kie session. can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-playground/tree/master/jbpm-simple-rest-client

That is a simple example that uses maven to create the rest client. You can use that against kid-workbench to interact with tasks, processes, etc.

That contains all the dependencies that you need.

HTH

Comment: when i tried to run the same sample and getting using getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner, i am getting exception that java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to post request: could not find writer for content-type application/xml type: org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.impl.JaxbCommandsRequest.

Comment: Your project is an ear with a web and ejb projects inside?

Answer (score 0):

@salaboy referenced a simple rest client that ONLY works in standalone mode, when you try to import kie-services you have to consider maven dependency exclusions but the bottomline is kie-remote is not yet ready to be deployed in a war thus far.